# What are invalid characters for a password in a Cisco router or firewall?

Tags: cisco

I'm trying to figure out what characters the Cisco router doesn't like when creating a password or pre-shared key. Please help me understand this. Thank you.

Comment: It should be noted: Don't use characters in your password that cannot be entered where you are asked for a password. For example, tab is bad choice from a web browser.

Comment: I like to use this [password generator](https://passwordwolf.com/?exclude=%3F"@!) to make random passwords and pre-shared keys because it lets you define what to exclude.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, the characters `?` and `[space]` are the only il-advised characters. The `?` indicates you are asking for help. The space indicates you are done with the password and moving onto the next command.

You should avoid `@` and `!` since they could interfere with other commands as you type them.

For IOS, `username (user) password 0 ...` everything to the end-of-line is the password - literally, even a "blind" trailing space! For an ASA, `username (user) password "..."` everything inside the quotes is the password. (<kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>v</kbd> will allow the input of `?` on both platforms) (the use of quotes allows use of spaces, but then excludes the use quotes in the password)

Comment: `username foo pass 0 foo bar` has a password of foo(space)bar. *everything* after 0 is the password. If you can type it, it's part of the password. (`"foo bar"` means the quotes are part of the password too.)

Comment: I once ran across a trick question about how to include a "?" in hostnames and passwords. Typing (as I remember it) a Ctrl-V allows the use of "?" and other special characters where you normally couldn't use them.

Comment: Ricky that may be true on a router but on a firewall after the space are more options like priv settings. For instance this would set the pass to 12345 and set priv to 15. `username test password 12345 priv 15`

Comment: tested with asa v9.2.1. The handling of backslash is simply broken.

Comment: In switches that use IOS you cannot have a space. The backslash worked fine for me in ASA v9.3.1.

Comment: 12.2.46 on a c3550 took `"foo bar"` (literally)